# UITableView throwing exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

I am getting the following error on a very simple UITableView:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d73210'
```

Here is my code:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return at least 1 section... I've tested this in a newly created UIViewController XIB called testes (add new .h and .c files and check the box to created XIB with it and also to make it a UITableViewController subclass) and it works fine.

How did you create the tableview?  Did you create it's own XIB like I wrote above or did you just throw a tableview into the MainWindow.xib file?  Try creating you own and you should be good.  Just make sure in AppDelegate to set the main view that gets added on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to the new tableview you create.  In IB, the UIViewController for the tableview should be set to testes subclass (which is a UITableViewController subclass)

App Delegate files

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class testes;

@interface testesAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    testes *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet testes *viewController;

@end
```

and

```
#import "testesAppDelegate.h"
#import "testes.h"

@implementation testesAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

And then in the viewcontroller .m file

```
#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change 0 to 1

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 10;
}
```

Comment: must have done it at roughly the same time...ill give you an upvote. great minds think alike.